# Why does let binding sometimes seem to fail to override a value?

Tags: message, let-binding, logging, eval-expression, inhibit-message

In this example, the message isn't shown, but it's still logged (`message-log-max` is ignored).

```el
(let ((inhibit-message t)
      (message-log-max nil))
  (hs-minor-mode))
```

The text `Showing all blocks ... done` is shown in the `*Messages*` buffer.

---

However, this overrides `message-log-max` as expected.

```el
(let ((inhibit-message t)
      (message-log-max-orig message-log-max))
  (setq message-log-max nil)
  (hs-minor-mode)
  (setq message-log-max message-log-max-orig))
```

Why isn't the first example working?
I've found let-binding `message-log-max` works in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

(You can just replace your `(hs-minor-mode)` to show the same effect, BTW.)

You're getting fooled by the echoing of the result of evaluation provided by a command such as `C-x C-e` or `M-:`.

Calls to `message` etc. within the `let` are ***NOT*** logged.  But if you use something like `C-x C-e` to evaluate your code then *that command* echoes the result of evaluating, and that echoing happens after the `let`.

In your second example, what gets echoed by `C-x C-e` is the result of evaluating the last sexp in the `let`, which is the second `setq`, which produces a numeric result (probably `1000`). That is, for the second example, you see `1000` logged, but not your `message` -- because the call to `message` (or `hs-minor-mode`) is not the last thing evaluated, so the message isn't returned as a result and isn't echoed by `C-x C-e`.

Comment: Note sure about `C-x C-e` or `M-:` - this is running from a `(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook (lambda () ... ))` (from my init file).

Comment: Are you sure what you think is happening is happening? What happens if you add another sexp after your call to `hs-minor-mode' in your first snippet? E.g. `M-: (let ((inhibit-message t) (message-log-max nil)) (message "AA") 42)` shows only `42` in `*Messages*`, as that's the *result* of evaluating.

Comment: (BTW, it's generally better to use named, not anonymous, functions in hooks.)